# MySQL - Batch Delete vs Individual Delete

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I have two processes that run using Python and SQlalchemy.

One process runs continously and inserts or updates certain rows in a MySQL table. 
Another process runs once every day, reads the rows from the table, moves data into a CSV and deletes the rows. It deletes all the rows through one delete statement

Once in a while I get "Lock Wait Timeout Exceeded" error from MySQL.

What are the advantages and disadvantages to delete one row at a time vs deleting all through one statement ?

In my process that runs once every day, I dont care if it takes more time.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64653/mysql-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the similar issue.